# Match single character between Start string and End string

Tags: regex, sed

I can't seem to understand regular expression at all.  How can I match a character which resides between a START and END string.  For Example

#START-EDIT

#ValueA=0

#ValueB=1

#END-EDIT

I want to match any # which is between the #START-EDIT and #END-EDIT.

Specifically I want to use sed to replace the matches # values with nothing (delete them) on various files which may or may not have multiple START-EDIT and END-EDIT sections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^#START-EDIT.*(#) *. *#END-EDIT$
```

Comment: the group (#) matches any occurrence of # and the '*' next to it matches for 0 or more occurrences of the same :) You may play around with '^' at the beginning and '$' at the end according to your requirements.

Cheers

Comment: This should be made non-greedy.

Answer (score 1):

sed is line based. you can easily search, replace based on regex in one line. But there is no really easy way to search/replace on multilines. AWK might do the trick.

If you have the regex on one line, the following command could be what you are looking for

```
sed -e "/^#START-EDIT.*#END-EDIT$//" myInput.txt
```